# Grid Vertical Scrolling

Tags: css, frontend, css-grid, vertical-scrolling

I have a grid with nested left and right grids. I want my left grid to take full height of the browser and be fixed in position. I want my right grid to get a vertical scroll bar as I add content to it.

```css
body{ margin: 0 0; padding: 0 0 ; }

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 500px;
}

.left{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows : repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap : 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: 500px;
}

.one{ background: violet; }

.two{ background: indigo; }

.three { background: blue; }

.right{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4,1fr);
  grid-gap : 5px;
}

.four{ background: green; }

.five{ background: yellow; }

.six { background: orange; }

.seven{ background: red}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="one">1</div>
            <div class="two">2</div>
            <div class="three">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="four">4</div>
            <div class="five">5</div>
            <div class="six">6</div>
            <div class="seven">7</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you plan to get the left grid to occupy full height and remain fixed if you have `grid-auto-rows: 500px`? This will overflow the container in many cases.

Here's a revised version of your code, with a fixed left-side grid, and `grid-auto-rows: 500px` with `overflow: auto` on the right-side grid.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr; /* switched from percentages for spacing efficiency */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  /* grid-auto-rows: 500px; */
  height: 100vh; /* new */
}

.left {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  /* grid-auto-rows: 500px; */
}

.right {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr); */
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: 500px; /* new */
  overflow: auto; /* new */
}

.one   { background: violet; }
.two   { background: indigo; }
.three { background: blue;   }
.four  { background: green;  }
.five  { background: yellow; }
.six   { background: orange; }
.seven { background: red     }
body   { margin: 0 0; padding: 0 0; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="four">4</div>
    <div class="five">5</div>
    <div class="six">6</div>
    <div class="seven">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx for the help .  I just made the changes you  suggested but it is adding me an additional scroll bar on the right . I just want default browser scroll bar for right . And as i decrease the size of window left grid also get scrolled . Here is the link of my changes https://codepen.io/akash6019/pen/QXMZvY

Comment: What browser are you using? Nothing you're describing in your comment is appearing in your codepen. I'm testing in Chrome and FF.

Comment: When i use grid-template-rows: repeat(3,1fr); in left grid it is making left grid to scroll . I want one scroll which is browser default for my right grid . Please recheck the link again . I am using chome .

Comment: There is one profile picture in the left grid also . That's why your are not seeing any changes .

Comment: The second scroll bar is appearing because of the size of the content in the left grid. You either have to allow the content to shrink to 0, or allow it to overflow. Here's your codepen with `overflow: hidden` on the left grid: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjGwvr

Comment: Thank You for your kind help . Actually i just started learning web development and making my portfolio website :D .

Comment: Great!
This one helped me <3